# How to enable CloudFront only on prod environment with aws amplify?

Tags: aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I added cloudfront to hosting with

```
amplify configure hosting
```

but once this is pushed to the cloud all environments are updated so that dev and prod now have it.

If I remove it from dev and push the changes then it will be removed from the prod.

How can I have cloudfront only on the prod evnironment?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you'd do this. You may be able to add conditionals in the CloudFormation.

It's generally a best practice to have your dev & test environments mirror your prod environment. In Amplify, all environments are identical - obviously excluding the data and load on resources from using the service.

Also - without CloudFront, I'm not sure how you'd access the (deployed) front-end pages.

Can you elaborate on why you want to eliminate it?

**EDIT**
Amplify does not expose the S3 bucket or CloudFront distribution when hosting your front-end; so you won't be able to alter this behavior.

Comment: It takes time to distribute with CloudFront if I"m not mistaken. So there would be a delay after deployment.

Comment: Amplify deployment is very slow. It pushes your code to their backend, where you wait in a queue for the build to run. The backend build machines are slow and deploy via cloudformation is slow. The frontend also builds, slowly, the push into S3 is fast but then it needs to invalidate cloud front, which is slow. And if you're using nextjs there are edge lambdas that always seem to take forever to update. So yeah, builds are slow.